# How to append two variables with pipe in Linux/unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh, vi

I have two variables like below:

a=10 20 30 40
b=1000 2000 3000 4000
I need the desired output like below:

10|1000
20|2000
30|3000
40|4000

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show some code? Like your variables; are they `bash` variables?

Answer (score 0):

```
a1=($a) # if a & b are already arrays, you don't need this step
b1=($b) # directly go to the for loop. use a,b instead of a1,b1
for((i=0;i<${#b1[@]};i++))
do
echo "${a1[$i]}|${b1[$i]}"
done
```

should do it .

**Output**

```
10|1000
20|2000
30|3000
40|4000
```